# Magento2: host site without domain (with IP only), APACHE Server

Tags: magento2

http://55.55.55.55/alpha/ (not working)

http://alpha.com/ (working)

I'm struggling to host site without domain url and with IP only.

The site is working fine with domain url. However, when i try to configure with IP only, it does not work.

Please help,

Thanks,

Comment: This might be best asked in the Magento part of stackexchange. It's likely this is your answer - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134245/base-url-change-magento2-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow mentioned all the necessary 6 steps:

1) Go under stores->configuration->general->web->Search Engine Optimization->Use Web Server Rewrites->No

2) Go under stores->configuration->advanced->developer->Sign Static Files->No

3) Go under database and type following query and replace all base urls:

SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` where path like '%base%'

with,
http://55.55.55.55/alpha/

4) Please go and fix following (default) magento bug.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11453

5) Clear cache.

6) Please add index.php in url (if missing), while browsing.

Thanks,